# Can Dart or Flutter unit tests be automatically repeated?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing

When unit testing with Dart or Flutter
If there are 100 unit tests, if you run the `flutter test` command, 100 test codes will be tested once.
But I want to repeat this N times.
Is there a command or way to automatically start the test again after one full test and report if the test is broken?